# What the deuce? Why was my question deleted?

Tags: discussion

This one: [How to allow donations combined with a field where donators can write a message?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166510/how-to-allow-donations-combined-with-a-field-where-donators-can-write-a-message)

- You can see the **[cached version here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150909225205/http:/drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166510/how-to-allow-donations-combined-with-a-field-where-donators-can-write-a-message)** (for people who have less than 10k rep)

## My counter arguments

> From the moment the question has an answer, the question cannot be changed, since changing it would invalidate the answer. This is particularly true in this case, if you remove the part asking about a module, since the answer is only about modules you could use. – kiamlaluno

1) This is absolute BS. There are many answers on this site that recommend modules.

2) It does not invalidate the answer, as the module answer still answers my question. Heck, even if I had not asked for modules, I bet the answerer would've provided the same answer.

> You could have edited the question to say you weren't interested in
>   modules, but just removing that part would have made the question too
>   broad. – kiamlaluno

3) Too broad for you, but clearly not for the answerer.

> For questions, a post that no longer adds anything to the site should be deleted – Molot

4) This question has an accepted answer with 2 upvotes; thus, to say it doesn't add anything to the site it's BS.

> No, I left somebody else answer the question. – kiamlaluno

Why did you leave someone else to answer the question when you where the one who deleted? Heck, when I posted the question and before Molot answered it, I saw you several times active on META (last seen on your profile). The fact that you kept avoiding my question, when clearly it was aimed at you, says a lot.

#### After all the countless hours, efforts, answers, comments, edits, I've put on this site, this is how I get treated, like a newbie? I get my question deleted due to some technical nonsense? This is how ♦ mods treat top contributors?

#### Then I refuse to provide any more answers until my question gets undeleted.

As per my counter arguments, you can conclude that the answer was deleted due to a personal agenda/vendetta OR moderation incompetence.

Comment: I just locked this.   Editing in responses to other answers and comments back into the question has made this clear as mud.  I will clean this up and unlock it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

> "Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme, distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

And from [network-wide rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/225745):

> For questions, a post that no longer adds anything to the site should be deleted. Basically, this includes most closed questions that cannot be improved and reopened.

Since there is no reasonable way for your question to stop being module request (without [chameleoning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/225745) it first, and that's a bad thing), it met deletion criteria. If it would stay unanswered, there might be a chance for edit that does not invalidate answer and deletion might not be a right thing, but fact that there was answer, and thus there was no proper way to edit, pretty much sealed the fate of this question.

Comment: I would like to get my question undeleted. If I take out the `Is there any module that already does this?` It should no longer qualify as a module question and it does not affect/invalidate the answer. Agree?

Comment: You can try. It's not me who needs to agree, but moderators.

Answer (score -1):

Mołot explained why questions are removed. I will add some details about the question and why it cannot be re-opened or undeleted.

The question was asked on July 24, and answered on July 26; it was closed as off-topic on August 27, less than 12 hours after a minor edit pumped it on the front page. It was then deleted on December 31.

> [image]

From the moment the question has an answer, the question cannot be changed, since changing it would invalidate the answer. This is particularly true in this case, if you remove the part asking about a module, since the answer is only about modules you could use.
In the case there were no answer, there have been 4 months between when the question was closed, and when it was deleted. You could have edited the question to say you weren't interested in modules, but just removing that part would have made the question too broad. So, if the question didn't have answers, it would have been deleted because it was not improved in any way. And the last edit that removed the part asking for a module didn't improve the question.